# ZXingBarcodeImageView Navigation Back - Xamarin Forms - System.ArgumentException: Found empty contents

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvm, zxing

Tengo una vista con la implementación del ZXingBarcodeImageView

```
<zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE"
                                                  BarcodeValue="{Binding QrCode}"
                                                  VerticalOptions="End"
                                                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                  HeightRequest="180"
                                                  WidthRequest="180" Margin="0,15">
                                <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                                    <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
                                </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                            </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
```

y tengo en el ViewModel la propiedad, el error radica cuando navego a la anterior vista, lanzando el siguiente error.

> System.ArgumentException: Found empty contents

En el ViewModel, se tiene lo siguiente:

```
public class CarnetViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
{
      protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

      public CarnetViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
      {
          NavigationService = navigationService;
      }

        /// <summary>
        /// The qr code
        /// </summary>
        private string qrCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the qr code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The qr code.
        /// </value>
        public string QrCode
        {
            get => qrCode;
            set { SetProperty(ref qrCode, value); }
        }
}
```

NOTA: Se tiene implementado el Framework Prism para la navegación y MVVM.

Realizando un seguimiento encontré un error más detallado, pero igual no se como puedo controlarlo.

```
Unhandled Exception from source=AndroidEnvironment
System.ArgumentException: Found empty contents
at ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeWriter.encode (System.String contents, ZXing.BarcodeFormat format, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] hints) [0x00008] in <ccd33a3710ff407d90a31fb75c8c27de>:0 
at ZXing.MultiFormatWriter.encode (System.String contents, ZXing.BarcodeFormat format, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] hints) [0x00033] in <ccd33a3710ff407d90a31fb75c8c27de>:0 
at ZXing.BarcodeWriterGeneric.Encode (System.String contents) [0x0002f] in <ccd33a3710ff407d90a31fb75c8c27de>:0 
at ZXing.BarcodeWriter`1[TOutput].Write (System.String contents) [0x00013] in <ccd33a3710ff407d90a31fb75c8c27de>:0 
at ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.ZXingBarcodeImageViewRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<regenerate>b__0 () [0x00000] in <6a1930ceea034eb28eda2834838f88c6>:0 
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <a10f61e70eeb434e952fef884856c199>:0 
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <a10f61e70eeb434e952fef884856c199>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.48(intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: ¿Has limpieado y re-compilado? Por otro lado, agrega el código de tu viewmodel y de las demás clases para poder reproducir tu escenario :D

Comment: Si ya limpie, recompile y sigue presentandose.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un workaround rapido para ello utilizando un elemento hidden en tu vista, y el BarcodeValue obtenerlo de ahi, en tu caso quedaría por ejemplo:

```
        <!-- Not Visible Entry -->
        <Entry x:Name="QRFakeEntry" Text="{Binding QrCode}" IsVisible="False"/>
        <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE"
                                  BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=QRFakeEntry}"
                                  BarcodeValue="{Binding Path=Text}"
                                  VerticalOptions="End"
                                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                  HeightRequest="180"
                                  WidthRequest="180" Margin="0,15">
            <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
            </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
        </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
```

workaround basado en
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/763

Esto funcionó para mi,
Saludos!